# database try-catch block code does not execute

Tags: java, mysql, exception, try-catch

I want to connect to the MySQL database through try-catch method. But my eclipse console keeps on showing "GOT AN ERROR" which is in my catch block. Please help me through this as I am new to java and exception handling. Following is my code.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;        
     protected  void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String task;
        String tm;

         task = request.getParameter("task");
         tm= request.getParameter("reminder_time");
        // System.out.println("task = "+task+"time ="+tm);
         try {
             SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
                Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(tm);
                java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
            //System.out.println("Time=");
            Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reminder","xyz","xyz123");  
             String INSERT_RECORD = "insert into ToDo values(?, ?)";
                    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
                      pstmt.close();
                      pstmt = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_RECORD);
                      pstmt.close();
                      pstmt.setString(1, task);
                      pstmt.close();
                      //pstmt.setDate(2, timestamp);
                      pstmt.close();
                      int rs= pstmt.executeUpdate();

            if(rs!=0){

//              response.sendRedirect("success.html");
//              return;
                PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                out.println("Successfull");     
                pstmt.close();
                con.close();

            }
            else{
            //  response.sendRedirect("error.html");
                PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                out.println("Failed");
            }

        } 
         catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Got an ERROR");
        }
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Call `e.printStackTrace()` to get more details about the exception (or at least print `e.getMessage()`). Also, not sure it is a good idea to close the statement before executing the query.

Comment: add this `System.out.println("Got an ERROR: "+ e.getMessage);` and in next line  `e.printStackTrace()` in your `catch` block. This will give you the error cause and stack trace. Then you will see what is going wrong.

Comment: All those PreparedStatement closes are going to be causing problems. It is good to attempt to close the PreparedStatement, but it is better to either move the close calls into a finally block or better still use a try-with-resources statement

Answer (score 0):

To find out the database access failure that invoked your catch clause try code like this.

```
catch (SqlException e) {
    System.out.println("database exception");
    System.out.println(e); 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
catch (Exception e)
    System.out.println("unexpected exception");
    System.out.println(e); 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    throw;
}
```

You need the line number that generated the exception, and `printStackTrace()` shows it to you.  Or, in Eclipse's debugger, set a breakpoint at your exception handler and examine the exception.

Your code shows this:

```
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            pstmt.close();
```

The second of those lines generates an exception, because you cannot call an method without an object.

**Pro tip**: In many scenarios in the real world, failure to complete a connection is very different from failure to complete an `INSERT` query or some other query. Connection problems usually mean the database server is shut down or your network is working incorrectly.  Query problems often mean you have some kind of problem in your program or database logic.  You might choose to use two try/catch blocks, one for the connection and another for the query.

**Pro tip**: Always indent your code to show nesting correctly. Eclipse (and most IDEs) do this for you.

Comment: I followed the steps you told and now I can see where the problem is. It is showing ParseException. The date entered by the user is unparseable. I am unable to throw ParseException in the doPost method. What shall I do now ?

Comment: This should be the topic of another question.